# Retrieve base from timer?

Tags: timer, libevent

I'm testing `libevent`'s timer functionality.

I set the timer with the following, which fires the timer every 3 seconds:

```
shared_ptr<event_base> base(event_base_new(), std::ptr_fun(event_base_free));
vector<shared_ptr<event> > std_events;
...

static const timeval three_sec = { 3, 0 };
event* tev = NULL;

tev = evtimer_new(base.get(), NULL, NULL);
rc = event_assign(tev, base.get(), -1, EV_PERSIST, timeout_cb, tev);

rc = event_add(tev, &three_sec);
shared_ptr<event> ptr(tev, std::ptr_fun(event_free));
std_events.push_back(ptr);

rc = event_base_dispatch(base.get());
```

In the `timeout_cb`, I want it to run a few times then exit the dispatch loop:

```
void
timeout_cb(evutil_socket_t fd, short events, void *arg)
{
    static int count = 0;
    int rc = 0;

    event* timer = (event *)arg;
    event_base* base = NULL;      

    if(count++ == 5) {
        struct timeval delay = { 1, 0 };
        rc = event_base_loopexit(base, &delay);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid a custom struct for the `arg` in the callback.

`event_base_loopexit` needs the `base_event`. Is it possible to get the `base_event` from the `evutil_socket_t` or the `event*` `timer`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fetch the `base`.

`event_get_base` will retrieve the base:

```
event_base* base = event_get_base(timer);
```

`event_get_assignment` will also retrieve the `base`:

```
event_base* base = NULL;
event_get_assignment(timer, &base, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```